# ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line xx is out of range for file IService.cs. File has xx lines

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to use [SonarScanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-msbuild/) to scan and analysis my project C# source code. I can build all my projects without error. I have run all these commands successfully.

> dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
>
> dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"test"
> /d:sonar.host.url="http://localhost:9000"  /d:sonar.login="token"
>
> dotnet build

But when I run the last command below, it got an error

> dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="51bae4230d438e567f84b8310f129938c73dd3f2"

This is the error message:

> ERROR: Error during SonarScanner execution INFO:
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Line 15 is out of range for file
> xx/IService.cs. File has 14 lines.
> at org.sonar.api.utils.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:43)
> at org.sonar.scanner.DefaultFileLinesContext.checkLineRange(DefaultFileLinesContext.java:63)
> at org.sonar.scanner.DefaultFileLinesContext.setIntValue(DefaultFileLinesContext.java:56)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.MetricsImporter.consumeFor(MetricsImporter.java:66)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.MetricsImporter.consumeFor(MetricsImporter.java:38)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.ProtobufImporter.consume(ProtobufImporter.java:73)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.RawProtobufImporter.accept(RawProtobufImporter.java:49)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.ProtobufDataImporter.parseProtobuf(ProtobufDataImporter.java:97)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.ProtobufDataImporter.importResults(ProtobufDataImporter.java:72)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.DotNetSensor.importResults(DotNetSensor.java:101)
> at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.DotNetSensor.execute(DotNetSensor.java:81)
> at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
> at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ProjectSensorsExecutor.execute(ProjectSensorsExecutor.java:49)
> at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:360)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
> at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:150)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:137)
> at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:123)
> at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:72)
> at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:66)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:46)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
> at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:189)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.execute(EmbeddedScanner.java:138)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:112)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:75)
> at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61) ERROR: The SonarScanner did not complete successfully 14:43:25.558
> Post-processing failed. Exit code: 1

I went to check IService.cs, it is 14 lines and see no issue there. In fact, as mentioned, I can build all my projects without error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most similar issue I can find:

[SonarQube analyses issue Line is out of range for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53493806/sonarqube-analyses-issue-line-is-out-of-range-for)

Basically you are looking any hidden character in the file